# From the include, how to show and hide the content according to the requirement?

Tags: angularjs

I have a template in include. i am using that in 2 seperate instance in same page. how to i conditionally show the information within it?

code :

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("main", function($scope) {
  $scope.firstTitle = true;
  $scope.secondTitle = true;
});
```

html :

```
    <div ng-controller="main">

          <div class="show-first">
            Your first info is :
            <ng-include src="'info.html'"></ng-include>
//only need to show first tittle
          </div>

          <div class="show-second">
            Your second info is:
            <ng-include src="'info.html'"></ng-include>
//only need to show second tittle
          </div>

        </div>

         <script type="text/ng-template" id="info.html">
            <div>
              <h1 ng-if="firstTitle">Info to show in first </h1>
              <h1 ng-if="secondTitle">Infor to show in second </h1>
            </div>
        </script>
```

[Live](http://plnkr.co/edit/hZkfPZo6sY5B7p1gHugP?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show / hide segments of components based on a certain value/condition. You can follow this approach as well.

```
<div ng-show="isSectionShown()">
    <h3>First Section Title</h3>
    <div> Section Contents </div>
</div>

<div ng-show="isSectionShown()">
    <h3>Second Section Title</h3>
    <div> Section Contents </div>
</div>

angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
   $scope.selectedSection = 'First';

   $scope.isSectionShown = function() {
      // This is for demonstration only, you can come with your implementation here to allow multiple checkings

      return angular.equals($scope.selectedSection, 'First');
   }
});
```

With similar conditional segments, you can use, `ng-show, ng-hide, ng-if` like statements.

Comment: I am able to understand your answer, can you show as a with demo please? or update my plnkr?

Comment: Refer the below Plunker for more details. Let me know if you need further help. http://plnkr.co/edit/KyJGJI?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use two controllers separately to control the display of the template: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mOFzXM7exIRgglYdyQdS?p=preview).

```
.controller("oneCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.firstTitle = true;
  $scope.secondTitle = false;
}).controller("twoCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.firstTitle = false;
  $scope.secondTitle = true;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you separate your templates.

```
<script type="text/ng-template id="info1.html">
    <div>
        <h1 ng-if="firstTitle">Info to show in first </h1>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template id="info2.html">
    <div>
        <h1 ng-if="secondTitle">Info to show in second </h1>
    </div>
</script>
```

The only other option is to access it form different controllers so you can turn one off and the other on. Separating the templates is the most versatile option IMO.